# Can Idea + s after Endless (adj.)?

Tags: adjectives, grammatical-number

Can Idea + s come after endless (adj.)?
= Endless Ideas?
Is that correct?

Because I wonder endless should be uncountable.

Comment: "Endless source of ideas"

Comment: "Endless succession of ideas" might sound more natural. But 'endless' can have the sense 'innumerable' as well as 'unbounded', as a quick check in a dictionary will show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Idea" is a conventional noun, not a noncount noun like water or money. In your sentence "endless" functions as an adjective, which can modify count or noncount nouns (adjectives are themselves not divided into count or noncount). There would be an error if the construction were "endless idea," that is treating a count noun like a noncount noun. But as written, it's fine. I sense your problem might be with the logic of "endless" applying to any noun: Endless guests came to the party. But endless means "having or seeming to have no limit."  So that "endless ideas," may "seem" to be countless, which is sufficient for "endless."